# What array is better?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I need to save 2D levelmap. So should i use 2D-array or simple array and break it inside condition? 
Some examples:

```
var map2D[3][3]={
    [1 , 2 , 3 ],
    [1 , 2 , 3 ],
    [1 , 2 , 3 ],
}

var map[9]={
    1, 2, 3,
    4, 5, 6,
    7, 8, 9
}
```

So what map is easier to read and walkthrough?

Comment: Everything depends on what you want to use this array.

Comment: depends which language you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to represent a 2D data - use a 2D array.

The performance gain/loss is negligible if any, but the **READABILITY** is an important factor here, and programers will most likely find it much easier to follow the logic of using 2D array for 2D space.

Comment: what if map cell has extra values and arrays go to 2d and 3d? Is it should be same choice to go 3d?

Comment: @Sugar If it is more clear - then yes. However, at some point it gets less readable, and you might want to encapsulate an element as an object.. This is case dependent of course and the main issue is again - readability.

Answer (score 2):

For **simple code** use 2D array.

For **better performance** use 1D array. (This is correct for C++ and several other languages)

Answer (score 0):

Use the two dimensional array because it will (usually) give you cleaner code avoiding index calculations.